# how to stop CAKeyFrameAnimation in Iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation

hi iam currently working in simple amimation app in which i implement  following code

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
// CGPathMoveToPoint use to move position 
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 160, 90);
//move image to state x Axes Right 
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,-30, 90); 

animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.path = path;
CFRelease(path);

animation.duration = 15.0;
animation.repeatCount = 0;
animation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[[ballImageView1 layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"zposition"];
```

but my problem is  that whenever animation is completed  then anmation stop func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question.  It sounds like your animation stopped and you what it to repeat indefinitely?

By setting repeatCount = 0, it will only go through the animation once.

You need to set repeatCount = HUGE_VALF to get it to repeat over an over.

repeatCount
Determines the number of times the animation will repeat.

@property float repeatCount
Discussion
May be fractional. If the repeatCount is 0, it is ignored. Defaults to 0. If both repeatDuration and repeatCount are specified the behavior is undefined.

Setting this property to HUGE_VALF will cause the animation to repeat forever.

If you just want the last frame of the animation to stay visible then set removedOnCompletion = NO.